# Error s3:PutBucketPolicy Access Denied when publish static-website in Serveless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a couple of sites deployed in a project using the Serveless framework and the serverless-lift plugin. After Amazon changed its S3 creation policy, the ability to create and publish a site broke.

```
provider:
  name: aws


constructs:
  landing:
    type: static-website
    path: dist

plugins:
  - serverless-lift
  - serverless-offline

package:
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
```

I tried different options and ran into two problems.
First, if you leave the configuration empty (as in the example), an error occurs

> API: s3:PutBucketPolicy Access Denied

```
resources:
  Resources:
    BucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
          Bucket: ${construct:landing.assetsBucketName}
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Sid: AllowPublicReadAccess
                Effect: Allow
                Action: 
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                Resource: 
                  - 'arn:aws:s3:::*'
                Principal: "*"    
                Condition:
                  Bool:
                    aws:SecureTransport: 'true'
          PublicAccessBlockConfiguration:
            BlockPublicAcls: false
            BlockPublicPolicy: false
            IgnorePublicAcls: false
            RestrictPublicBuckets: false
```

when I try to add a configuration, and somehow change the rights of S3, I get an error

> Resolution error: ${construct:landing.assetsBucketName} does not exist. Properties available on ${construct:landing} are: cname

Can anyone help me how to write the config?